# How to randomly fill a region with non-overlapping rectangles using NumPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How do I randomly fill a given rectangular region with rectangles of random sizes without the rectangles overlapping each other using NumPy?

My idea is to create a two dimensional array with the same shape as the region, fill the array with zero, then for each rectangle required, randomly select two coordinates inside the array that are not set, make a rectangle from the two points, and fill the region inside the array corresponding to the rectangle with 1.

Somehow it isn't working:

[image]

Code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from random import randbytes, randrange

def random_rectangles(width=1920, height=1080, number=24):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width/100, height/100), dpi=100, facecolor='black')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_axis_off()
    grid = np.zeros((height, width))
    for i in range(number):
        free = np.transpose(np.nonzero(grid == 0))
        y1, x1 = free[randrange(free.shape[0])]
        y2, x2 = free[randrange(free.shape[0])]
        if x1 > x2: x1, x2 = x2, x1
        if y1 > y2: y1, y2 = y2, y1
        grid[y1:y2, x1:x2] = 1
        w, h = x2-x1, y2-y1
        x, y = x1, -y2
        color = '#'+randbytes(3).hex()
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((x, y), w, h, fill=True,facecolor=color,edgecolor='#808080',lw=1))
    
    plt.xlim(0, width)
    plt.ylim(-height, 0)
    plt.axis('scaled')
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
    plt.show()
```

I don't understand, I have tried this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import random

class Grid:
    def __init__(self, x1, x2, y1, y2):
        assert x2 > x1 and y2 > y1
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2
        self.subgrids = []
        self.divisions = dict()
        self.last_subgrid = None
    
    def random(self):
        if not self.subgrids:
            x = self.x1 + random.random() * (self.x2 - self.x1)
            y = self.y1 + random.random() * (self.y2 - self.y1)
            return x, y
        else:
            if not self.last_subgrid:
                subgrid = random.choice(self.subgrids)
                self.last_subgrid = subgrid
                return subgrid.random()
            else:
                x, y = self.last_subgrid.random()
                self.last_subgrid = None
                return x, y

    
    def set_subgrid(self, shape):
        x1, x2, y1, y2 = shape
        assert x2 > x1 and y2 > y1
        assert self.x1 <= x2 <= self.x2 and self.y1 <= y2 <= self.y2
        if not self.subgrids:
            eight = [
                (self.x1, x1, self.y1, y1),
                (x1, x2, self.y1, y1),
                (x2, self.x2, self.y1, y1),
                (x1, x2, y1, y2),
                (x2, self.x2, y1, y2),
                (self.x1, x1, y2, self.y2),
                (x1, x2, y2, self.y2),
                (x2, self.x2, y2, self.y2)
            ]
            for a, b, c, d in eight:
                if a != b and c != d:
                    subgrid = Grid(a, b, c, d)
                    self.subgrids.append(subgrid)
                    self.divisions[(a, b, c, d)] = subgrid
        
        else:
            for a, b, c, d in self.divisions:
                if a <= x1 < x2 <= b and c <= y1 < y2 <= d:
                    self.divisions[(a, b, c, d)].set_subgrid((x1, x2, y1, y2))

def random_rectangles(width=1920, height=1080, number=24):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width/100, height/100), dpi=100, facecolor='black')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_axis_off()
    grid = Grid(0, width, 0, height)
    for i in range(number):
        x1, y1 = grid.random()
        x2, y2 = grid.random()
        if x1 > x2: x1, x2 = x2, x1
        if y1 > y2: y1, y2 = y2, y1
        grid.set_subgrid((x1, x2, y1, y2))
        w, h = x2-x1, y2-y1
        color = '#'+random.randbytes(3).hex()
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((x1, y1), w, h, fill=True,facecolor=color,edgecolor='#808080',lw=1))
    
    plt.xlim(0, width)
    plt.ylim(0, height)
    plt.axis('scaled')
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
    plt.show()
```

It doesn't work:

[image]

---

### ***I did it***

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import random

class Grid:
    def __init__(self, x1, x2, y1, y2):
        assert x2 > x1 and y2 > y1
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2
        self.subgrids = []
    
    def random(self):
        if not self.subgrids:
            x = self.x1 + random.random() * (self.x2 - self.x1)
            y = self.y1 + random.random() * (self.y2 - self.y1)
            four = [
                    (self.x1, x, self.y1, y),
                    (x, self.x2, self.y1, y),
                    (self.x1, x, y, self.y2),
                    (x, self.x2, y, self.y2)
                ]
            for a, b, c, d in four:
                if a != b and c != d:
                    subgrid = Grid(a, b, c, d)
                    self.subgrids.append(subgrid)
        else:
            random.choice(self.subgrids).random()

    def flatten(self):
        if not self.subgrids:
            return
        
        result = []
        for subgrid in self.subgrids:
            if not subgrid.subgrids:
                result.append((subgrid.x1, subgrid.x2, subgrid.y1, subgrid.y2))
            else:
                result.extend(subgrid.flatten())
        
        return result

def random_rectangles(width=1920, height=1080, number=24):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width/100, height/100), dpi=100, facecolor='black')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_axis_off()
    grid = Grid(0, width, 0, height)
    for i in range(number): grid.random()
    rectangles = grid.flatten()
    for x1, x2, y1, y2 in rectangles:
        w, h = x2-x1, y2-y1
        color = '#'+random.randbytes(3).hex()
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((x1, y1), w, h, fill=True,facecolor=color,edgecolor='#808080',lw=1))
    
    plt.xlim(0, width)
    plt.ylim(0, height)
    plt.axis('scaled')
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

I finally did it, but the result is not what I imagined, and I don't think my implementation is good enough. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "*result is not what I imagined*" The key question is what did you precisely expect and how can you objectively measure if a result is "good enough"? Besides this is may be wise to separate the design of an algorithm from a specific implementation in Numpy/Python.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I wanted the rectangles to have very similar (but not equal) sizes, and have gaps between them.

Comment: The thing is the size and the position of the first rectangle statistically bias the one of the other rectangle draw later because the remaining space is decreasing. This cause the distribution not to be uniform if you do the operation iteratively. For example if you start with a big rectangle in the centre, then others can only be small. That being said, doing this in a statistically correct way is pretty tough. One can adapt the size/location iteratively to correct the bias (hard) or try to draw them simultaneously (harder) or simply reduce the size to avoid problems (easy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a better result by tackling your problem in another direction.

What you have done is to split up the sample space into subspaces for each time you sample, then you sample within said subspaces again (or something similar to that).

If you split your sample space beforehand you can get a grid of even sampling spaces of which you can sample from instead:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(42069)


def get_rects(n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Params
    ------
    n: number of rectangles
    """
    ceilsqrtn = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(n)))
    n_grids = ceilsqrtn * ceilsqrtn

    # Create rectangles in the "full space", that is the [0, 1] space
    rects = rng.uniform(size = (n, 4))

    # To ensure that the rectangles are in (x1, x2, y1, y2) format where
    # Upper left corner is (x1, y1) and bottom right corner (x2, y2)
    # Result looks fine without this, but it's a nice to have
    rects[:,:2].sort(1)
    rects[:,2:].sort(1)

    # Create a ceilsqrtn x ceilsqrtn even grid space
    flat_grid_indices = rng.choice(n_grids, n, False)
    offsets = np.unravel_index(flat_grid_indices, (ceilsqrtn, ceilsqrtn))

    # Move each rectangle into their own randomly assigned grid
    # This will result with rectangles in a space that is ceilsqrtn times larger than the [0, 1] space
    rects[:,:2] += offsets[1][..., None]
    rects[:,2:] += offsets[0][..., None]

    # Scale everything down to the [0, 1] space
    rects /= ceilsqrtn

    return rects
    

def plot_rects(rects: ArrayLike, width: int = 10, height: int = 10):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height))
    for x1, x2, y1, y2 in rects:
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((x1, y1), x2 - x1, y2 - y1, facecolor='gray', edgecolor='black', fill=True))
    plt.show()

rects = get_rects(150)
plot_rects(rects)
```

Result:
[image: rectangles]

It is a good start at least. To obtain rectangles with other characteristics you could simply sample from another distribution, such as a Gaussian. With that, you would obtain more similar rectangles, but you would need to clip the ones that overflow into other subspaces or something like that. Another alternative are truncated distributions within the [0,1] domain.

EDIT: Code cleanup and better comments