# place Ellipses in a rectangle without overlapping each other

Tags: python, numpy

How do I randomly fill a given rectangular of bottom left corner (0, 0) and top right corner (350,250) with Ellipses of random sizes without the Ellipses overlapping each other using NumPy?

and get the data of the Ellipses placed as center point, radius1 and radius2.

I saw this method but didn't got much

[How to randomly fill a region with non-overlapping rectangles using NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72389315/how-to-randomly-fill-a-region-with-non-overlapping-rectangles-using-numpy)

What I tried is mentioned below I have generated the radius of ellipses required but no idea how to place them all in the rectangle without overlapping.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random

Area_of_quad = 350 * 250
Af_ell = 0.4                   # Vol Fraction of Ellipses
Area_of_Ell = Af_ell*Area_of_quad
Ell_range_r1 = np.array([20,12.5,10])
Ell_ragne_r2 = np.array([0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9])
Area_of_ell_each = Area_of_Ell/len(Ell_range_r1)
rad = []
for i in range(len(Ell_range_r1)):
    area = Area_of_ell_each
    while area >= 0.01*Area_of_ell_each:
        r1 = Ell_range_r1[i]
        r2 = random.choice(Ell_ragne_r2)*r1
        Ar_ac = math.pi*r1*r2
        area -= Ar_ac

        rad.append([r1,r2])
```